# How can I integrate employees and schedules into an Aloha POS system?

Tags: integration, point-of-sale

I'm trying to integrate employees and labor schedules from an external system into an Aloha POS. After extensive web searches and reading any available documentation it appears that /newdata allows much of the Aloha POS setup data to be modified programatically.

I'm still looking for specifics as to which particular files need to be altered for employees and schedules. Also, are there particular versions of Aloha at which this external maintenance will no longer work?